# How do I catch all invalid URLs using JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

How do I catch these invalid URLs so that I return a proper error resource?

Thanks.

Basically, I want to override the "The resource not found Page." and instead I want to return an XML describing the error.

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form.  What URLs are you talking about, what makes them invalid, and where are you trying to "catch" them?

Comment: I actually thinks this is a valid question. Web servers treat invalid uris as 404. But one wants to catch this for different purposes, such as logging... or overriding as Kuma wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit in which JAX-RS implementation you are using.

If you are using [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/), you can create an `ExceptionMapper` that catches `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException`. That enables you to build and return a custom `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        return Response.status(exception.getErrorCode()).build();
    }
}
```

I'm a bit unsure on how to do this with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), but maybe you can create an `ExceptionMapper` that catches `com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException`.

Comment: The question is how to do it in a way that is not depedent on the implementation. So one could switch implementations easily...